# .NET How many listeners can an event have?

Tags: .net, events

I am writing a piece of software which is modelling trains and train station departure boards.  The trains store how many minutes ahead of / behind schedule they are.  Each instance of the departure board subscribes to a constantly changing subset of trains.

We are writing the application to be able to handle tens of thousands of trains and hundreds of thousands (possibly millions) of departure boards.

Rather than have the trains maintain a list of references to each subscribing departure board, my plan was to use .NET events.  Each time some information about the scheduling of the train changes, the instance of the train class raises an event.  Each instance of the Departure Board class simply adds or removes event listeners for trains to which they are subscribing.

Is there a limit to how many listeners an event can have?  If so, what is the limit and how will performance degrade?

Thanks,
Rik

Comment: This is really not that difficult to measure with a scratch program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's some code that adds a million handlers to a delegate and it works fine:

```
Action<int> action = n => Console.WriteLine(n);

for (var i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)
{
    var i2 = i;
    action += n => Console.WriteLine(n + i2);
}

action(42);
```

I would, however, look at using Microsoft's Reactive Extensions, rather than raw events, to handle your eventing. Using delegate will get incredibly difficult to perform any kind of aggregation and filtering at the scale you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a limit to how many listeners an event can have?

How much memory have you got? ;p In terms of the numbers you're talking about, it should be fine - but frankly I don't think that it is a great approach. But:

```
static void Main()
{
    EventHandler handler = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6000000; i++)
    {
        var obj = new Spoof();
        handler += obj.Bar;
        if ((i % 1000) == 0) Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("done");
    Console.ReadKey();
    handler(null, null);

}
class Spoof
{
    public void Bar(object sender, EventArgs args) { Console.WriteLine("hi"); }
}
```

> If so, what is the limit and how will performance degrade?

Basically, approximately linearly.

However, I really don't think this approach is ideal - it has issues such as being limited to a single app-domain (making it hard to distribute between nodes), and it is **really** easy to get unexpected memory scenarios when using events like that. Also, unsubscribing will get pretty expensive since it needs to scan the subscriber list.

**Personally**, I'd be using something like redis pub/sub, or some other dedicated pub/sub system. The boards could subscribe to trains (or maybe lines) they're interested in, and trains (or lines) just broadcast to those named channels.